# Slider Issues - Weird reset on last slide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider

I'm working on a simple slider for a website. Obviously it's a work in progress and I haven't completed the script or the styling, but I have run into an issue. By clicking on the next button I'm able to loop through all of the images, but when I reach the end and try to get it to go back to the first one, the data-slide attribute for all of them resets to 0 and all the slides display. I know that I can work around this by using the .first() function, but I'm curious to know why this is happening. It doesn't really seem to make sense, but I'm pretty new still. Here's a demo:

http://codepen.io/heatherthedev/pen/tdibB/

Edit:

I do want to make sure that the data-slide numbers don't get reset, I'm planning to use them for navigation elements in the slider.

Comment: Is there is a reason why you want to recreate the wheel here by making your own gallery? You are already using jQuery, why not use one of the plethora of jQuery picture slider plugins?

Comment: Look at line 6 and then at line 17 of your Javascript and see if you can see the inconsistency. Or just look at what Steve said :)

Comment: Thanks! I know there are a ton available, but my boss prefers that we write our own. Plus it's helping me learn a lot faster than using someone else's :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $firstSlide variable was setting all of your slides "data-slide" to 0. The reason this is happening is because `$('.slide').attr('data-slide', 0);` sets all of the data-slide properties on all elements with the class `.slide` to 0.

Another way to write this would be

`$('.slide').data('slide',0);`.

Changing that line to

`var $firstSlide = $(holder).find('[data-slide=0]');`

finds the first slide with the "data-slide=0" value.

Example http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xoBaE

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

"When I reach the end and try to get it to go back to the first one, the data-slide attribute for all of them resets to 0" - this actually isn't happening at the end; it happens the very first time you toggle slides, due to this line:

```
var $firstSlide = $('.slide').attr('data-slide', 0);
```

That's a setter call; it sets the `data-slide` custom HTML attribute of every element with a class of `.slide` to `0` when it runs, which is every time the "next" button is clicked.

In looking at your code, I think you're mixing up the use of a custom HTML attribute you've created called `data-slide` with use of the jQ .data() function, which actually attaches data to the element(s) its run against.

In terms of why every slide is then displayed when you get to the end, it's because you else condition has this line...

```
$firstSlide.addClass('active');
```

... where the value of `$firstSlide` is actually a jQ collection of all your slides - hence why they all display. You need to instead find the element with a `data-slide` of `0` and save that to `$firstSlide`, then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Just put:

```
var $firstSlide = $('.slide').eq(0);
```

instead of:

```
var $firstSlide = $('.slide').attr('data-slide', 0);
```

The `data-slide` attribute is reseting because you say so in that line and then you are not seeing the first slide again because `$firstSlide` is not defined, so when trying to run the else code you get an error.